# Apache redirect domain to folder is not specified

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, httpd.conf

I need to redirect my domain to a sub folder if a sub-folder is not specified in the URL request.

For eg.

a) If request comes from "domian.com" or "www.domain.com", I want to redirect it to "www.domain.com/page".

b) However, if request comes from "domain.com/page2" or "www.domain.com/page2", i do not want the request to be redirected to "www.domain.com/page".

I have been trying some permutations in the Virtual Host but with no luck. Below is my code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      Options +Indexes
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$1
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Page [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass         /  http://www.domain.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://www.domain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this instead:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$   [NC]
  RewriteRule .* /Page [L]
```

Comment: Why, does use the rule when there is a URI-path?

Comment: What I need is if I hit on domain.com or www.domain.com, it should be re-directed to www.domain.com/Page and if I hit on www.domain.com/Page2, it should not be redirected.

Comment: That's what the rule-set is supposed to do. Make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test. And replace [L] with [R,L] temporarily so you can see the redirected URL.

Comment: still does not work. I have cleared the cache also. Below is the rule I am using:
`code`RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(domain2\.com|domain3\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]                  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !. [NC]
RewriteRule .* /Home [L]

Comment: There is an error in the first rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1` Should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1` It is appending `domain.com` to the substitution URL-path, not redirecting to `http://domain.com`

Comment: I modified my answer. Please give it another try. Do you see what's the redirected URL modifying the flags.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also, how to check the flags by the re-directed URL?

Comment: Try with these options `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`. Replace [L] with [R,L] temporarily to see the redirected URL.

Comment: Just disable `MultiViews`. Can't be enabled for mod_rewrite to work correctly.

Comment: I am pretty sure both versions of my answer work as expected, so the problem is not with the mod_rewrite rules. There is another reason for the issue that I can't figure out.

Comment: Hmmmm thanks for your help. I will keep trying different combinations.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure the cache is cleared before any test.

Answer (score 0):

The [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)`%{REQUEST_URI} !^/$1` excludes every request, so the `RewriteRule` is never used.

If you want to rewrite just the root dir, use a specific [regular expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) `^/$` instead. You must also wrap the rules in the appropriate `<Directory>`, because everything enclosed applies to the file system directory, *not* the URL path

```
<Directory /path/to/documentroot>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^$ /Page [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, the above rule will redirect to /Page irrespective of the fact if a sub folder is provided in the url or not. What I need is selective re-writing. 

Also, I tried the above rule, it is not re-drirecting to /Page also.

Comment: @AkhileshAggarwal It will rewrite only for the root directory. If you specify any URL path, e.g. `www.domain.com/abc`, it will *not* rewrite to `/Page`, but serve `/abc` instead.

Comment: I tested the rule, it is not redirecting for root directory :(

Comment: @AkhileshAggarwal I have tested this in a .htaccess only, not in the virtual host/directory. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @AkhileshAggarwal I tested the first version in a .htaccess, and the second version in my virtual host test environment. For my virtual host it is `<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>`, your `DocumentRoot` will be somewhere else. And don't forget to reload the configuration or restart Apache.

Comment: Yes I am restarting the server. Will keep trying stuff. Thanks